# Display react Bootstrap Popover when click on a cell in react-bootstrap-table 2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Design the section with react-bootstrap-table2. I just want to show popover with options on clicking the particular cells. Is there any way to combine react-bootstrap-table2 and react bootstrap popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using **formatter** in bootstrap table props.
Reference link : 
https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html

Here i my Code

```
List.tsx
    const columns: ColumnProps<User>[] = [    {
                dataField: 'action',
                text: '',
                formatter: ColumnFormatterFactory,
                style: { overflow: 'inherit' },
            },
    ];
        <BootstrapTable
                        bootstrap4
                        bordered={false}
                        classes="mb-5 table-fit"
                        columns={columns}
                        data={this.records}
                        filter={filterFactory()}
                        keyField="id"
                        noDataIndication="No Users yet."
                        remote={{ sort: true, filter: true }}
                        rowClasses="clickable-row"
                        onTableChange={handleTableChange}
                    />


ColumnFormatterFactory.tsx

export const ColumnFormatterFactory = (cell: any, row: number, rowIndex: any, formatExtraData:any) => {
    return (
            <Dropdown>
                <Dropdown.Toggle
                    id={`${row.id}-dropdown`}
                >
                <span >More</span>
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu>        
            <Dropdown.Item >one1</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Divider />
            <Dropdown.Item >two</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Divider />
            <Dropdown.Item >three</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>       
            </Dropdown>    
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import all the required components and just simply combine them in the way that works for you. You do not need to use the Button the docs recommmend. I have a working example here. https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-bush-8dxgo it's ugly and I just threw it together but it will give you a good idea of how to combine them.
Next time try and post some code you've tried.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but , Im asked about Combine the bootstrap popover in react-bootstrap-table, not with reactstrap popover. i found solution for my question